# Programatically set NFC_PAYMENT_FOREGROUND setting for HCE in Android

Tags: android, nfc, payment, hce, android-tap-and-pay

I am trying to set priority for a payment card in a foreground activity, but `setPreferedPaymentService()` won't work until `categoryAllowsForegroundPreference()` returns `true`. However, this is tied to the "Foreground priority" (NFC_PAYMENT_FOREGROUND) system setting.

Has someone encountered a similar problem? How can I change that setting programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of the the setting "Foreground priority: Use payment app in foreground, even over default" (`Settings.Secure.NFC_PAYMENT_FOREGROUND`) is to give the device user an option to prevent apps from doing exactly this. Consequently, if there was a programmatic way to re-enable this option (after the user intentionally disabled it), having this option would be pointless.

Therefore, the answer is: You can't programmatically enable that system setting from your app.

However, what you can do is ask *the user* to reconsider their choice. You could do this, for instance, by sending a [`CardEmulation.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT` intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation#action_change_default) to let the user select your app as the default. Or you could navigate the user to the Tap & pay settings (using a [`Settings.ACTION_NFC_PAYMENT_SETTINGS` intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#action_nfc_payment_settings)).